# Fastest way to search for string within a string, given a set of constant factors

Tags: php, string

I have a long string, in which I need to determine whether there is an occurrence of a short string. It sounds very simple, and it is, using `strpos` I can perform

```
strpos($longstr, $shortstr);
```

Which would get the job done, however there are some facts that I know for certain:

- the short string will always start on a new line
- the short string will always be 10 characters long (multibyte)
- the short string will always start with the characters "чь"
- the short string will always end with a new line after the 10th character
- the short string can only occur once, further occurrences are meaningless and disregarded

Having the above conditions in mind, it makes no sense to search for the string in question in any position other than 0 on a new line, however, how can I know where the new lines are if I don't go through the whole long string.

Is there anything that can be improved in getting the job done, performance-wise, compared to `strpos`?

Answer (score 3):

You could explode() (http://php.net/explode) your $longstr on the "\n" character, and iterate over the results ... But honestly, since you'd have to do that in PHP, I'm pretty sure a straight up strpos() call will be faster.

If you could come up with a regular expression, that might work - but again, I think that will be slower than strpos().

Comment: Agreed, using `strpos` should likely be the fastest way – no need to over-complicate something for which a very simple solution already exists.

Comment: I will be testing these suggestions for sure. It is very interesting how doing the whole work can actually be faster than figuring out how to do less work.

Comment: It would be more complicated if it would be n-th occurence that is interesting you, but as far as you are interested in first one `strpos` seems to be best solution: quickest and most memory efficient.